Google Places iOS SDK Uses Broken Cryptography API (MD5)
I'm using the Google Places SDK on my iOS Application. I ran a dynamic security scan and it identifies that Google Places uses MD5 hashing functions which have been deprecated since iOS 13.
Specifically, the scan identifies that CC_MD5 methods are being called for the following functions:
[GMPx_PHTSnapshot calculateFlagsHashForSnapshot:]
[GMPx_CCTLogContext hashForFilePath]

The names suggests that these functions are not being used for encryption or for security. Does anyone know if this indeed the case? Or is there a security concern here and Google Places isn't secure to use?
Thanks in advance!

Could you please raise a question in Google Public Issue Tracker?
